# Can a batsman be stumped from a no ball?

Tags: rules, cricket

In cricket, can a batsman be out stumped from a no ball?

Answer (score 9):

[Law 24](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/) covers no ball - section 16 states that a batsman can only be out in the following ways off a no ball:

- handled the ball
- run out
- obstructing the field
- hit the ball twice

so a stumping doesn't count.

Answer (score 1):

No, stumping is not out off a no-ball.

But, a runout is valid off a no-ball. How is stumping different? If the batsman attempts to make a run, is outside his crease, and the wicketkeeper takes the bails off, this is a runout.

If the batsman is just outside his crease as a followthrough of his shot, and has not made any attempt to run, and if the wicketkeeper takes the bails off, this is a stumping.

Answer (score -4):

A batsman cannot be out stumped on a no-ball. But they can be run-out on a no-ball. A stumping is a run-out wherein the wicket keeper has possession of a ball the entire time after the ball was delivered, and runs the batsman out.

Comment: -1 as this adds nothing to TrueDub's answer and is also technically incorrect (if the batsman has set off for a run, it's not a stumping).